# how to calculate the partial formula of this sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to get the partial formula of
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k2^{-k}$?
I know that the formula of a sequence of partial sum is from $k=i$, $\frac{q^i-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$.

Comment: See the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$
and 
$$xf'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^k=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)$$

Take $x=\frac{1}{2}$ in the last equality.

Answer (score 1):

Start with:
$$
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} z^k = \frac{1 - z^{n + 1}}{1 - z}
$$
Then:
$$
z \frac{d}{d z} \sum_{0 \le k \le z} z^k = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} k z^k
$$
Compute the derivative of the left hand side by the alternative above and evaluate at $z = 1/2$.